# ordering in sql result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have custom query to get data from DB. I am having a problem with ordering.

Here is what I am using to get data.

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM wp_terms AS a INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS b ON a.term_id = b.term_id
            WHERE
                b.taxonomy = "ticker" AND(
                    a.name LIKE "aa%" OR b.description LIKE "aa%"
                )
            ORDER BY 
                CASE 
                    WHEN(
                            a.name LIKE "aa%" AND b.description LIKE "aa%"
                        ) THEN 1 
                    WHEN(
                            a.name LIKE "aa%" AND b.description NOT LIKE "aa%"
                        ) THEN 2 
                    ELSE 3
                    END,a.name ASC
            LIMIT 0, 10
```

The result is showing like that.

[image]

Show I need a result to be show like

> AA

First then other results.

it is working with single character

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM wp_terms AS a INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS b ON a.term_id = b.term_id
            WHERE
                b.taxonomy = "ticker" AND(
                    a.name LIKE "v%" OR b.description LIKE "v%"
                )
            ORDER BY 
                CASE 
                    WHEN(
                            a.name LIKE "v%" AND b.description LIKE "v%"
                        ) THEN 1 
                    WHEN(
                            a.name LIKE "v%" AND b.description NOT LIKE "v%"
                        ) THEN 2 
                    ELSE 3
                    END,a.name ASC
            LIMIT 0, 10
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this result is actually reproducible?  Can you setup a demo and paste the link here?

Comment: You want to order by only name or name and description both.

Comment: Order by only name

Comment: If you only want to order by name then why you are using CASE. You can use only a.name ASC.

Comment: if there is not valid match than I need with description if not a in name availabel

Comment: You could add order by length

Comment: Yes, that worked

Answer (score 2):

The best possible solution for alphabetic ordering to sort with length first and then with the values -

```
SELECT a.*,
  b.*
FROM wp_terms               AS a
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS b
ON a.term_id     = b.term_id
WHERE b.taxonomy = "ticker"
AND( a.name LIKE "aa%"
OR b.description LIKE "aa%" )
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN( a.name LIKE "aa%"
    AND b.description LIKE "aa%" )
    THEN 1
    WHEN( a.name LIKE "aa%"
    AND b.description NOT LIKE "aa%" )
    THEN 2
    ELSE 3
  END,
  LENGTH(a.name),
  a.name ASC LIMIT 0,
  10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT a.*, b.* FROM wp_terms AS a INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS b ON a.term_id = 
  b.term_id
            WHERE
                b.taxonomy = "ticker" AND(
                    a.name LIKE "aa%" OR b.description LIKE "aa%"
                )
            AND(
                CASE 
                    WHEN(
                            a.name LIKE "aa%" AND b.description LIKE "aa%"
                        ) THEN 1 
                    WHEN(
                            a.name LIKE "aa%" AND b.description NOT LIKE "aa%"
                        ) THEN 2 
                    ELSE 3
                    END)
            order by a.name ASC
            LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: Pasting code solutions are great but it would be better if you include explanations and reasoning of the proposed approach and maybe point out mistakes in the initial question.

Comment: @muhammad this will not with single character

Comment: @TejasGajjar I provided just a hint that how you can, you may use the whole name or prefixing with table name thanks.